# Android Picture Activity

Tags: android

I have created the activity for taking picture using Builtin image Capture activity but still not available to store picture in sdcard and view the captured image.The Intent is started and i am able to take the picture but when i click on ok(save), nothing haappens. Below is my activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.picturelayout);
    imageForUpload = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.trackMePicture);
    btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getImageUri(this));
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
}

/**
 * @return
 */
private Uri getImageUri(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    File file =newFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),context.getPackageName());
    if(!file.exists())
        file.mkdir();
    File newFile=new File(file,new Date().toString()+".jpg");
    Uri imagePath=Uri.fromFile(newFile);
    return imagePath;

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==TAKE_PHOTO_CODE ){
        if(resultCode==-1){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Result code : "+resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Uri imagePath=getImageUri();
            Bitmap b;
            try {
                b = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), getImageUri(this));
                imageForUpload.setImageBitmap(b);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Result code : "+resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Request  code : "+requestCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the search.  There are about 6 million questions of how to save an image from the camera to the sd card.  Just look at the "Related" list to the right ---> Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no code in your `onActivityResult()` that would store the bitmap `b` in a file.
You can have a look at the [PicHelper.storeBitmap()](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/helper/PicHelper.java#L180) method from my Zwitscher app on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
final Bundle extras = data.getExtras(); 
if (extras != null) {
    Bitmap b = extras.getParcelable("data");
    imageForUpload.setImageBitmap(b);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it (for taking picture or browsing the media directory), hope it can help:

```
static int SELECT_IMAGE = 2000;
static int CAMERA_REQUEST = 2001; 

public void ProfilePictureDialog()
{
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setMessage("").setPositiveButton("Browse images", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {  
            Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);       
            startActivityForResult(gallery, SELECT_IMAGE); 

        }}).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {  

        }}).setNeutralButton("Take picture with camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {  
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
        }});
    builder.show();   
}





protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST)
        {  
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ImageView profilePicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilepic);

            photo = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, profilePicture.getWidth(), profilePicture.getHeight(), true);
            profilePicture.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
        else if(requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE)
        {
            Uri selectedImagePath = data.getData();

            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImagePath, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

            ImageView profilePicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilepic);

            photo = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, profilePicture.getWidth(), profilePicture.getHeight(), true);
            profilePicture.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
}
```